# How to make several async (RX) calls, and wait for them to finish in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to find a way to run some code after 3 async rx-fun's have finished.

Does anyone know a good way to do this by using RX?

I'm very new to this subject and don't have any runnable code to show, but I can say that the way I solve the problem in my code right now is by setting 3 Booleans to true after the async part of each fun has finished, and then in my code which is waiting, I am running a 4th function (RX Flowable) which I have subsrcibed to that checks if all 3 Booleans are true.

It looks a little like this:

```
// var async1IsDoneBoolean = false
// var async2IsDoneBoolean = false
// var async3IsDoneBoolean = false

fun async1() {
    // Start async work {
    // working..
    // done!
    // async1IsDoneBoolean = true
    // }
}
fun async2() {
    // Start async work {
    // working..
    // done!
    // async2IsDoneBoolean = true
    // }
}
fun async3() {
    // Start async work {
    // working..
    // done!
    // async3IsDoneBoolean = true
    // }
}

fun useResulfOfAsyncFuns() {
    // Create and subscribe to RX Flowable (will repeat until unsubscribed)
    // if (async1IsDoneBoolean && async2IsDoneBoolean && async3IsDoneBoolean) {
    // Run code after all async is done
    // }
}

 main() {
    async1()
    async2()
    async3()
    useResulfOfAsyncFuns()
 }
```

Comment: I don't know much about Rx, but you can easily do it with coroutines by joining on the Job, or if you want to get some result from the work awaiting on the Deferred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have been looking at coroutines and I am very tempted to go with that option. However, I forgot to mention that the async functions are calls towards a Room-database which is already implemented using RX, so I would have to do some changes to the code other places as well.

Comment: look at flatmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Completable.merge` with the various methods run async via `subscribeOn`:

```kotlin
Completable.mergeArray(
   Completable.fromAction { async1() }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
   Completable.fromAction { async2() }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
   Completable.fromAction { async3() }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.andThen(Flowable...)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the functionality I was looking for! Now my async functions run async, and then completes, and then the code/flowable in the "andThen()" :)